# How to read and store data from excel using java for selenium?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I would like to take an opportunity from you, am facing an issue to read and storing the data from excel.

Requirement: in my excel sheet having 10 rows and 5 columns, out of 10 rows I just want to execute only 5 rows(1,2,4,7,9)based on my flag status (YES/NO).
i want to read all required data from excel only one time and then need to get release excel.

what am exactly expecting, need to map like 1(row) with column and value
ex: 4 the row(test case) mapping with all columns and their values against to 4th row.
like 4,(col,value)

when i go for read ,i want fetch values from column names based on the row number(ex: 4 th test case)

i tried this way but didn't work for me,

```
HashMap<Integer,String[]> mymap=new HashMap<Integer,String[]>


mymap.put(rownumber(testcasenumber),new string[]{getcelldata(col),getcelldata(colval)});
```

in this case storing only test case number(r=row num) but other info col,values are not storing.

please assist me to get exact and perfect way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a Java API for excel such as JExcel at http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ or Apache POI at http://poi.apache.org/ can do what you want.